# how to get a specified discord text channel ID in discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am facing some problems in my discord bot using Discord.Net NuGet
i want to make my bot gets a channel id by only mentioning it
for example : $set-logChannel #kicked-or-banned-logs
and then it gets the ID of this channel and sets it as a variable in the database
any ideas, please? plus I want a tutorial PDF for Discord.Net NuGet library/package
anyone got the pdf please drop the link here and thanks !

Comment: There is document for the library on their [site](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/typereaders.html) . The page I linked there refers to TypeReaders, which is what your bot uses to parse commands. There is a built in type reader for channels. Simply set the parameter in your command that is meant to capture the channel mention as an ITextChannel data type. Then you can access all the properties of ITextChannel via that parameter, within your command logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a Socket(Text/Voice)Channel parameter named channel you can get the channel's Id with `channel.Id`:

```cs
[Command("logChannel")]
public async Task LogChannel([Remainder] SocketTextChannel channel)
{
    ulong channelId = channel.Id;
}
```